# How to provide text string to scraper not visible to visitors

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

What's the best way to provide a web scraper with a message (text string) that visitor's won't see?

Use case: My website is being scraped, which is fine, but I would like to provide some additional data to the scraper that is not visible to my visitors. How can this been done effectively?

I could wrap a piece of text in between a `<span>` tag, and hide it for visitors with JavaScript on page load, but scrapers will probably run the JavaScript and scrape the copy after the string has been removed. How can this be avoided?

Comment: "What is the best way" You must know that this question is extremely opinion-based. Maybe add some context of "best" (most efficient, most secure) to avoid your question being closed.

Comment: The answers depend on what sort of "scraper"

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name) tag? It isn't shown to your users (no need for javascript) and is probably where most web scrapers would start looking for metadata.

e.g. `<meta name="description" content="This page is about foo bar and baz">`

Comment: Unfortunately the scrapers ignore the meta tag. They "cut and paste" part of the body.

Comment: Perhaps [schema.org](https://schema.org/) could be an alternative in your case?

Comment: I don't understand, the scraper scrapes the body of my page... I want to add a message to that body, that is not visible to visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can hardly have any guarantee to make this message be received. Before writing a scraping script, the creator usually analyzes site structure in a common browser, so this message would be hidden. Then only some part of the document will be scraped in invisible headless mode, so neither a human will be able to see the message, nor the program will save it with any significant probability. Even if all the HTML will be scaped and saved for future processing, this processing also most probably will be done automatically and for some key elements only. So the only reliable way you can do this is blocking scraping at all with some message that will be received when the script creator debugs the script failure. But even in this case, it will be hard to separate the first attempt from other allowed attempts, so in this way, you may just block scraping at all.

You can try to log some notable message in the browser console though, with a hope that the script creator will see it in the preparation stage, when analyzing DOM structure and run some test code in the console. See how Facebook or https://ponyfoo.com/ do it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The idea would be to inject a message into the part that is being scraped, probably the text body of the document.

Comment: How you can be sure what part is to be scrapped and with what tools? If I am not mistaken, there are no reliable ways to differ a common client from a scraper, only some approximate heuristic that becomes more and more complicated.

Comment: Because I know the scrapers and I know what parts of the content they slurp and republish.

Comment: Then maybe it is worth to add this information to the question: what scraping tool is expected and how it can be detected on the server or client side.